# Connect to SSH server using Nautilus

Tags: 14.04, ssh, nautilus

Trying to connect to `SSH` server using `Ubuntu` file explorer. I have already connected to that server using `SFTP`, but now I would like to do the same via `SSH`.

[image: nautilus prompt]

By entering address and pressing connect because of unknown reason it connects to recent connection via `SFTP`. Why not `SSH`? How to fix it?

Comment: are you able to connect it via terminal ?

Comment: yes, I can connect via terminal

Comment: What do you want to "fix" exactly? I don't think nautilus distinguishes between ssh and sftp (file transfer *using* ssh). Or are you trying to start an ssh terminal session from the file browser?

Comment: I would like to browse files using ssh on remote machine

Comment: Isn't that exactly what [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) does?

Comment: Looks you are right. Thats why Nautilus does the same behavior for both commands. Thank you.

Comment: SSH credentials can be used with SFTP and it works all the time! :)

Comment: @AzkerM not all the time. Only if you don't remove `sftp subsystem, thought it is allowed on the most of the systems.

Answer (score 28):

Did you read [docs about Nautilus](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/nautilus-connect.html.en)? There are examples of what should work. And from your tried, only this one is mentioned:

```
ssh://username@servername.example.com/folder
```

but it is automatically rewritten in "recent servers" to:

```
sftp://username@servername.example.com/folder
```

Basically, there is no `ssh` file transfer protocol. `SSH` is just Secure Shell or secure channel to pass data. If you want to transfer files, you need to use something built upon it. And `sftp` is the most commonly used protocol for doing so. The only more common is `scp` and it is too limited for remote filesystem mounts.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but could you explain it a bit better? It's confusing to others when you say that there is no such protocol, yet the page you are linking to has such an example. ;)

Comment: sorry. I wrote it too fast. I put the examples, observed behaviour and tried to improve it. Is it more understandable?